# Manipulate php array of object with condition

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

It's maybe simple but i was really struggling with this,
i have an ouput data with array of object like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jumlah] => 50000
            [jenis] => 41
            [anggota] => 1
            [dk] => D
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jumlah] => 100000000
            [jenis] => 40
            [anggota] => 1
            [dk] => D
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jumlah] => 1000000
            [jenis] => 32
            [anggota] => 2
            [dk] => D
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [jumlah] => 4000000
            [jenis] => 40
            [anggota] => 1
            [dk] => D
        )

)
```

i want to minus all jumlah values but if there same jenis and anggota data value in different object it will manipulate just 1 object and skip the others,
can anyone help me how to do this? thank you and i really appreciate

Comment: Add the code you have tried

Comment: OK so you want to go through array, set `jumlah` to 0, but if `jenis` and `anggota` have been seen before, do nothing?

Comment: @JacobMulquin yap, little correction i want to go through array, set jumlah with exist value then minus it with 2500, but if jenis and anggota have been seen before, do nothing

Comment: @HarviDent before this i try via sql sir going through with query, but all results not like what i expect, then i try via php

Comment: We do not have a [mcve].  Please show your input and your exact desired output from that input.  If you've tried to code a solution, please include that so that your question is not such a target for downvotes.  You have received two answers that perform differently because your question is Unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a temporary array `lookup`, that has elements with key of `jenis,angotta`. We look through the data array, and modify the object if the key does not exist in the lookup array.

```
<?php

$array = [
    (object) [
        'jumlah' => 50000,
        'jenis' => 41,
        'anggota' => 1,
        'dk' => 'D'
    ],
    (object) [
        'jumlah' => 100000000,
        'jenis' => 40,
        'anggota' => 1,
        'dk' => 'D'
    ],
    (object) [
        'jumlah' => 1000000,
        'jenis' => 32,
        'anggota' => 2,
        'dk' => 'D'
    ],
    (object) [
        'jumlah' => 4000000,
        'jenis' => 40,
        'anggota' => 1,
        'dk' => 'D'
    ]
];

$lookup = [];

foreach ($array as &$object) {
    $key = $object->jenis . ',' . $object->anggota;
    if (!isset($lookup[$key])) {
        $object->jumlah -= 2500;
        $lookup[$key] = true;
    }
}

print_r($lookup);
print_r($array);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [41,1] => 1
    [40,1] => 1
    [32,2] => 1
)

Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jumlah] => 47500
        [jenis] => 41
        [anggota] => 1
        [dk] => D
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jumlah] => 99997500
        [jenis] => 40
        [anggota] => 1
        [dk] => D
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jumlah] => 997500
        [jenis] => 32
        [anggota] => 2
        [dk] => D
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [jumlah] => 4000000
        [jenis] => 40
        [anggota] => 1
        [dk] => D
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try like below:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $value->jumlah = $value->jumlah - 2500;
    if(isset($value->anggota) && isset($value->jenis)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

It will break the flow when there is anggota and jenis found.